# Как анимировать path, используя react icons и framer motion

Tags: reactjs, transition

```
import { IoMdMenu } from 'react-icons/io';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

// анимировать <IoMdMenu /> при помощи path анимации
```

Comment: Как именно анимировать?

Comment: при помощи path который есть в framer motion